# How to bootstrap values from a small non-normal sample size in order to get a confidence interval in R

Tags: r, distribution, bootstrapping

I have a list of 26 values that are right skewed and have a standard deviation of 22.08. I would like to find the 95% confidence interval for the mean within this data. I believe with a small sample size as I have here, bootstrapping would be the best way to go. What is the best approach through R to bootstrap then identify the 95% confidence interval?

```
0, 1.6, 2, 2, 3.4, 3.6, 4.4, 4.9, 5, 6.8, 8.7, 10.3, 10.5, 14.5, 15.2, 17.1, 
18, 20.9, 25, 25.8, 31.4, 31.9, 40.6, 59.9, 73.3, 85.5
```

Comment: Can you provide those 26 values here?

Comment: Question edited to include values!

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for the following?

```r
x <- scan(text = '0, 1.6, 2, 2, 3.4, 3.6, 4.4, 4.9, 5, 6.8, 8.7, 10.3, 10.5, 14.5, 15.2, 17.1, 18, 20.9, 25, 25.8, 31.4, 31.9, 40.6, 59.9, 73.3, 85.5', 
          sep = ",")

library(boot)
bootstat <- function(x, i) mean(x[i])

hist(x)
```

[image]

```r
set.seed(2022)
R <- 1e3
b <- boot(x, bootstat, R)
boot.ci(b)
#> Warning in boot.ci(b): bootstrap variances needed for studentized intervals
#> BOOTSTRAP CONFIDENCE INTERVAL CALCULATIONS
#> Based on 1000 bootstrap replicates
#> 
#> CALL : 
#> boot.ci(boot.out = b)
#> 
#> Intervals : 
#> Level      Normal              Basic         
#> 95%   (11.51, 28.75 )   (11.43, 27.90 )  
#> 
#> Level     Percentile            BCa          
#> 95%   (12.28, 28.75 )   (12.90, 30.44 )  
#> Calculations and Intervals on Original Scale
```

<sup>Created on 2022-07-31 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: So when I conduct a confidence interval test using a t-table with a t-value of 1.708, I get a very similar confidence interval. Should I have been expecting a tighter interval using boot strapping?

Comment: @NickA That depends on the data and its distribution. With skewed distributions results may be reliable or not, see, for instance, [this CV post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/186957/is-there-a-reliable-nonparametric-confidence-interval-for-the-mean-of-a-skewed-d).